# RaphaelJS 2.1 : relocated path must rotate but it's moving to it's original position

Tags: rotation, raphael

I'm new to RaphaelJS 2.1 and I don't understand why the path is moving to it's original position instead rotating in this code:

```
lego.translate(w/2-75,h/2-50);

lego.mousedown(eventDraw); // CLICK THE PATH!!!

function eventDraw(){               
lego.animate({transform:"R360"},2500);
}
```

The path rotates normally without the

```
lego.translate(w/2-75,h/2-50);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surracom/70Lwwvcw/)

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a transform that takes into account any existing transforms I assume.

In Raph this is made a bit easier by the '...' part of a transform string, which will take into account the existing transform. So..

```
lego.animate({transform:"...r360"},2500);
```

Would do it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/856rbv5L/)

[Docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform)

Comment: @ Ian. It works prety well. I must read the reference diligently. Many thanks.